# Fluentd + Rails setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rake-task, fluentd

We have two rails projects running for our app across ten machines and I'm trying to setup Fluentd to collect logs from all these boxes.

Following this [post](http://www.fluentd.org/datasources/rails), I was able to setup and aggregate logs for our user facing app where we have a rails server running.

The other project however is instantiated via a rake task and we have workers of this project who are listening to a RabbitMq for messages. I couldn't however do the same thing for this project(since we don't start a rails server maybe?). When I did a `rails s` on this project, I was able to see the logs being aggregated in the Fluentd `td-agent.log`. How can I pipe the logs of this project to Fluentd? Any heads up on this would be really helpful. TIA!